# Can't preview text file attachments in Outlook

Tags: outlook, windows-7-x64, preview

Something is wrong with my preview handlers in Outlook.

When I receive an email with a .txt attachment*, if I click on it, I get this message in the preview pane:

> This file cannot be previewed because of an error with the following previewer:
>
> **Windows TXT previewer**

*<sub>This problem applies not only to .txt files, but to any file types that are associated with the prevhost.exe preview handler (e.g., .rtf,. .sql, .reg, .bat, etc)</sub>

Following a suggestion from [this post](https://superuser.com/questions/762773/this-file-cant-be-previewed-because-of-an-error-in-the-microsoft-word-previewe), I deleted the Windows TXT Previewer from the following registry folder (after backing it up, of course):

`[HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\PreviewHandlers]`

This fixed the problem with Outlook (instantly), but broke the Preview Handler in Windows Explorer. (The Preview Pane in Explorer now displays "No preview available"). Conversely, when I restored the registry key, it fixed the Windows Explorer previewer, but it broke the Outlook previewer again.

Other things I've tried without success:

- attaching `prevhost.exe` to the debugger in Visual Studio, but I don't have the source code and can't read assembly.
- running `sfc /scannow`
- Disabling the Windows TXT previewer in `Outlook->Options->Trust Center->Settings->Attachment Handling->Previewers` (this just displayed a new message in the preview pane: "previewer has been disabled" with a button to re-enable it, which simply restored the original error message.

Other suggestions??

Comment: Is Outlook also 64-bit?

Comment: @Leftium: as a matter of fact, it's not. It's 32-bit. (Although I have another machine with Outlook 32-bit running on Win7 64-bit, and it is not having the same problem).