# How to define the scale and letter size on a print preview in Microsoft Edge or Internet Explorer through Java or JavaScript

Tags: javascript, css, internet-explorer, playframework, microsoft-edge

I have defined the Print CSS through media print in my CSS file.
In Chrome and Firefox, the same is getting applied. 
Whereas in Internet Explorer and Edge Browser, I need to manually select the scale to 75% and letter size to 8.5" * 11" and then print.
Is there a way through Java (As my backend runs on Play Framework) or JavaScript to define it in the first place? 
Thanks in advance

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Can I modify the Windows 7 preview pane so HTML files display just the text in the preview instead of rendering the html?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15375298/can-i-modify-the-windows-7-preview-pane-so-html-files-display-just-the-text-in-t)

Answer (score 1):

Some browsers (e.g. Chrome) do support the ability to specify *"hints"* via CSS to the browser in terms of printing preferences.

```
<style>
  @media print{
    @page{
      margin:1in;/* Default margin (for page content) */
      /*margin:0in; Sets margin to zero AND hides all the page #/date/URL fluff */
      size:landscape;/* Default to Landscape */
    }
  }
</style>
```

Sadly this is not an official standard yet and is considered experimental:
https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/@page/size

I'd certainly ***love*** all browsers to pick this up as it would be great to be able to provide sensible printing defaults to user agents.

Current support for Landscape & Margin:

- Chrome
- Vivaldi (based on Chrome)
- Brave (based on Chrome)(although there is currently no print preview)
- Opera (based on Chrome)

Current support for Margin only:

- Firefox

Test Page: https://css-printing-hints.glitch.me/